# Groovy throws error when "_-"are being used before root node while generating XML using XML markup builder .How to resolve it

Tags: groovy, markupbuilder

While generating an XML from JSON I need to use "_-"before root node name due to naming convention rules but `MarkupBuilder` throws an error in groovy scripting. How can I resolve it?

**input is JSON**

```
{"x": "efgw343", "y": "Ywth"}
```

****THE CODE I used is** **

```
import com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message;
import java.util.HashMap;
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper ;
import groovy.json.*

def Message processData(Message message) {

    def step = new JsonSlurper().parseText(message.getBody(java.lang.String))
def writer = new StringWriter()
def xmlRequest = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer)
xmlRequest.mkp.xmlDeclaration(version: "1.0", encoding: "utf-8")
xmlRequest._-bbc(xmlns:"urn:xyz.com"){
           I_A(step.x)
           I_B(step.y)
}
message.setBody(writer.toString())
return message
}
```

**the Output I am expecting is**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<_-bbc xmlns='urn:xyz.com'>
  <I_A>efgw343</I_A>
  <I_B>Ywth</I_B>
</_-bbc>
```

**THE ERROR MESSAGE I am getting is**

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: _ for class: groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
Possible solutions: mkp
    at groovyide_com.processData(groovyide_com:21)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at com.groovyide.ExecutorService$1.run(ExecutorService.java:144)
Error:
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

Can anyone help in resolving this? Because this would reduce our code's length drastically.

Comment: Instead of `xmlRequest._-bbc` does `xmlRequest."_-bbc"` work?  The issue is `xmlRequest._` looks like you are accesing a property named `_` and then subtracting `bbc` from it.

Comment: See https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/4882303306170368, click "Execute Script" and then click "Output".

Comment: I tried to concise the first two lines like this ` ` ` def xml = new StringWriter().with { w -> new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(w) {
  xml.mkp.xmlDeclaration(version: "1.0", encoding: "utf-8") ` ` ` . But I am getting an error as ` ` `org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
groovyide_com: 22: unexpected token: xml @ line 22, column 3.
     xml.mkp.xmlDeclaration(version: "1.0", encoding: "utf-8")
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object ` ` ` .can you clarify me where I am  wrong @Jeff Scott Brown

Comment: @Yalamatihemanthkumar, read the first comment carefully. That's the answer